# Edited question to bring it into scope, how does one get the "on-hold" removed?

Tags: support, on-hold

I edited a good (in my opinion) [question](https://superuser.com/questions/931514/bulk-download-images-from-google-image-search-to-disk) from another user in order to bring it into scope. My edit was approved, but the question is still on hold.

What is the right way to bring someone who can remove the tags attention to the question, or will it happen naturally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your edit has pushed the question into the Reopen Review Queue, and will be assessed by the community as to whether they think it should be reopened.

You don't need to do anything more for now.  Once you have [3,000 reputation](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) you would be able to vote to reopen the question, which would also put it into the queue for reviewing.

For those who can see the queue: https://superuser.com/review/reopen/393427

Comment: Thanks. I'm still new enough here that I wasn't sure the right way to proceed